# Tomcat session between multiple tomcat instance

Tags: session, tomcat, load-balancing

We have 10 Tomcat instances all running the same web application. We use a hardware load balancer, and it forwards the requests to an arbitrary server. How can I maintain sessions across all Tomcat instances in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Tomcat's clustering to provide session replication between nodes.

You should also consider using sticky sessions as directing each request to an arbitrary server requires that every server has the latest session data at all times. That is expensive in time, network bandwidth and server memory. There is also the issue that many clients send multiple requests in parallel. If they go to different servers they will see different session states.

With 10 servers you should consider the `BackupManager` which maintains session state on the current node (the master node for that session) and one other node (the backup node for that session) with all the other nodes only knowing the master and backup node for that session. The default `DeltaManager` (which maintains session state on all nodes) does not scale as the network traffic increases with the square of the number of nodes (with the `BackupManager` the network traffic scales linearly). Note that it is a common misconception that one node acts as the backup for all sessions. This is incorrect. The backups are distributed around the cluster so for a 4 node cluster (A,B,C,D) with 60 active sessions then node A will have 15 master sessions (60/4), 5 backups for sessions with the master on B, 5 backups for sessions with the master on C and 5 backups for sessions with the master on D.