# Httpsession attribute is not passing to another class when both classes are being served from two different servers

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

I have two servlets. Lets name it Class A and Class B. Class A is setting a true/false flag in Httpsession attribute, this flag is being read by Class B (which is also a servlet). Everything working fine when my both classes A and B are being served by same server or same cluster of servers, but problem arising when Class A is served from Server 1 and class B is served from Server 2.
Please note that right now code is in core Java (servlet), i am not using any standard Framework like SpringBoot etc.

Need help to fix this issue using java code. Any help will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

PFB some code snippet for reference:

```
Class A extends HttpServlet{

----
---

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("Flag", "true");

}


Class B extends HttpServlet{
-------
-----
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    strFlagYN = (String) session.getAttribute("Flag");
    logger.debug("Flag value is ::", strFlagYN);

}
```

Regards,
Neeraj K Kar

Comment: I assume that you properly defined `strFlagYN` as a String variable.

Comment: @Spectric yes, strFlagYN is declared as String
just FYI- for 90% of transaction code is working fine only for 10% where request is serving from 2 servers (load balancer) problem is coming

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391040/tomcat-session-between-multiple-tomcat-instance) will help.